# Parser error when connecting with Socket.io in react native

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-native, websocket, socket.io

I deployed a node server with socket.io server on port **my_socket_url:3000** and test it on localhost javascript file

```
const socket = io('my_socket_url');
console.log(socket);
socket.on('connection',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('new_message',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

works fine!. But now in react native I installed socket.io-client in my application and tried to connect such that way with facing the error

```
parser error
```

also tried to resolve the problem by following pre-asked questions in communities

Comment: This might be a bit too late. However, anybody facing this issue should take a look at this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036250/3282822